# Rails 2.3.14/Rails 1.9.3p125 on FreeBSD 9.0 failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have encounter a strange error after running

```
$ portmaster -a
```

last week. It reports

```
method `xmlschema' not defined in Date
in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb line 26 method `remove_method'.
```

I cannot rollback nor I know where the problem come from. I have tried reinstall everything in ports by

```
$ portsnap fetch update
$ portmaster -Fa
```

then reinstall all the gems. Unfortunately the error still persist. Could a guru help me out? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work when you edit the ruby file conversions.rb and comment out the following line:

```
remove_method :xmlschema if base.instance_methods.include?(:xmlschema)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems fixed the problem so far.